# JavaScript: unable to access object properties

Tags: javascript, object, backbone.js, properties, handlebars.js

I'm having trouble accessing the properties of a simple object.

This is what I get when I run `alert(JSON.stringify(user))`:

```
{"username": "david", "biography": "Hello world."}
```

But this is what I get when I run `alert(user.username)`:

```
undefined
```

I've also tried `user["username"]` with the same result. This is in the context of a Backbone application using Handlebars. Here is the Backbone part:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'http://api.example.com/user',
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    ":username": "profile"
  },
  profile: function (username) {
    var user = new User({id: username});
    user.fetch({
      beforeSend: authenticate,
      success: function() {
        var profile = new Profile({user: user});
        profile.render();
      }
    });
  }
});

var Profile = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    var source = $("#profile").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    user = this.options.user;
    var html = template(user);
    $("#content section").html(html);
  }
});
```

What might be the cause such an issue?

Comment: How do you define user ? Are you sure it's an object and not a string ?

Comment: is it a backbone model? I ask thi because you added a backbone tag to your question.

Comment: Yes, the code in my post is within a view into which the `user` object is passed. I ran `alert(typeof user)` and it returns `object`. I'll add some more context to the question.

Comment: Try user.toJSON. I bet it will come back as a function.

Comment: Yep. Sure enough, it's a function...

Comment: can your print the `user` object to console using `console.log(user)` and see what is printed

Comment: you access the properties of a backbone model using the get method or by looking into the attributes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you user object is a backbone model, then try this

```
console.log(user.get('username'));
or
cosole.log(user.attributes.username);
```

Comment: Yep, this worked. I just passed `{username: user.get("username"), biography: user.get("biography")}` into the Handlebars template function and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me

```
   var user = {"username": "david", "biography": "Hello world."};
alert (user.username);
alert (user["username"]);
```

Comment: Yes, normally it would work. I believe my issue has something to do with the Backbone context...

Comment: I understand. Can you please update the question and include some more information so that we could help

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify will look for a toJSON function and use the return value of that as the JSON it uses.

Backbone probably does some fancy coding to make it easier to use its model objects. Since they don't think you want all the junk they put in, they provided a clean toJSON() result for you.

@Rayweb_on has the rest of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me not to always trust JSON.stringify :-)